# Inconsistent behavior of 'greater than or equal' and 'equality' operators regarding 'undefined'

Tags: javascript

If the equality (strict or not) operator returns `true` for `undefined`...

```js
console.log(undefined == undefined)
```

...why does the *greater or equal than* operator returns false?

```js
console.log(undefined >= undefined)
```

The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Greater_than_or_equal) says that the operands are compared using the [Abstract Relational Comparison](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison), but that refers to *greater than* (or *less than*) part. Thus, it seems to me that the *greater than or equal* should provide the same algorithm for equality, isn't that correct?

Comment: Because `NaN >= NaN` is `false`.

Comment: @FelixKling I know that, and also that `NaN === NaN` is false. But `undefined === undefined` is true. If `undefined === undefined` were false, that behavior of "greater than or equal" would be consistent, but it's not.

Comment: It doesn't matter what `undefined === undefined` is. The `>=` operator converts its operands to numbers (if there are not numbers or strings) (well, technically it's not the operator but the algorithm you linked to; step 4d). And `undefined` gets converted to `NaN`: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumeric

Comment: @FelixKling now *that* is the answer, thanks. So the fact that IsLooselyEqual or IsStrictlyEqual don't convert them to numbers creates this behavior, which is, again, inconsistent.

Comment: I can agree with that. Type conversion rules are basically arbitrary, especially across languages. If you want "reasonable" code, avoid (implicit!) type conversion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thus, it seems to me that the greater than or equal should provide the same algorithm for equality, isn't that correct?

No, that algorithm is not involved here. The spec [defines the evaluation of `>=`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) as

> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *RelationalExpression*.
> 2. Let *lval* be ? GetValue(*lref*).
> 3. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *ShiftExpression*.
> 4. Let *rval* be ? GetValue(*rref*).
> 5. Let *r* be ? IsLessThan(*lval*, *rval*, `true`).
> 6. If *r* is `true` or `undefined`, return `false`. Otherwise, return `true`.

So the only algorithm involved is [`IsLessThan`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islessthan), which will convert its operands to numbers if they are not already numbers (or strings).

`undefined` gets [converted to `NaN`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumeric) and [`Number::lessThan`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-lessThan) returns `undefined` if any operand is `NaN`, which, according to step 6 above results in `false`.